# NestJS + Socket.io: No messages received

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

I'm developing a NestJS backend with socketio.

Unfortunately, I'm running into an issue. I'm running this code on the server:

```html
import { WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer, SubscribeMessage, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
@WebSocketGateway()
export class SettingsGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    @WebSocketServer() server;
    users: number = 0;

    async handleConnection(){
        Logger.log("Hello! New user!")
    }

    async handleDisconnect(){
    }
    @SubscribeMessage('settingsChange')
    handleMessage(client:Socket, payload:string):void{
        Logger.log("received message");
    }
}
```

And get the "Hello! New User!" message, but the server is never displaying the "Received message" string. On the clientside, I send a message using this:

```
console.log("Emit stage activated")
this.socket.emit('settingsChange',setting)
```

and get the "Emit stage activated" console log, so I know that the command is at least being run.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on? Thanks for the help!

Also: Both socket.io and socket.io-client are v6.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: The frontend app was connecting to the API hook for the backend, not the actual backend, leading to a good connection but not through websockets.

Comment: can you elaborate on the solution?